# Error using object from different class

Tags: c++, oop

Foo.h

```
class Foo{
private:
    void printSpecialBar(Bar b);//syntax error: Identifier Bar
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

void Foo::printSpecialBar(Bar b)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

Bar has the default constructor and one that takes two int's.

What is the problem with the syntax error? I tried using the scope resuloution operator Bar::Bar b but it didn't fix it.

Comment: You have to include `Bar.h` in `Foo.h`

Comment: @awesomeyi is that in addition to including it in Foo.cpp?

Comment: Since you are using `Bar` inside one of `Foo`'s member function declarations, you must tell the compiler what it is. Otherwise, the compiler thinks that you made a typo. Forward-declaring `Bar` with `class Bar;` would give compiler enough information to compile your program, as long as the declaration precedes the point where `Bar` is first used.

Comment: @awesomeyi Can certainly include it, and it would fix the problem. However, it is not strictly required here: a forward declaration would be enough.

Comment: @awesomeyi and where possible, a forward declaration is always preferred to including the full type definition. Generating chains of .h files can substantially increase compile times and sometimes lead to errors.

Answer (score 1):

A typical practice would be to put

```
class Bar;
```

in `Foo.h`, before any reference to `Bar` class, and include the actual class like

```
#include "Bar.h"
```

in `Foo.cpp`.

Comment: Well it really has nothing to do with #pragma once. So either position would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Foo.h` references Bar, either use a forward declaration or `#include "Bar.h"` in `Foo.h`